# How to return the corresponding line that matches our search keyword in whoosh?

Tags: python, python-3.x, whoosh

Lets say given file `a.txt`:

```
hello world
good morning world
good night world
```

Given the keyword that I want to search is `morning`, I want to use whoosh python library to return the line that matches the keyword `morning` in the text file `a.txt`. So, it will return `good morning world`. How can I achieve this?

Update: Here is my schema:

```
schema = Schema(title=TEXT(stored=True),
              path=ID(stored=True),
              content=TEXT(stored=True))
```

then I add a writer add_document to content field

Comment: What is the purpose of using the whoosh library?

Comment: Can you show your index schema.

Comment: @pjcunningham updated

Comment: @AnnaSemjén is it more easier for integration with python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index the text file per line and store the line number as a `NUMERIC` field and the entire line as an `ID` field (storage is cheap, right!).

Something like the following (untested):

```
schema = Schema(
    title=TEXT(stored=True),
    path=ID(stored=True),
    content=TEXT(stored=True),
    line_number=NUMERIC(int, 32, stored=True, signed=False),
    line_text=ID(stored=True),
)


ix = index.open_dir("index")
writer = ix.writer()

with open('a.txt') as f:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(f):
        writer.add_document(
            title='This is a title',
            path='a.txt',
            content=line,
            line_number=line_number,
            line_text=line,
        )
```

Clearly you could extend this to index multiple text files:

```
files_to_index = [
    {'title': 'Title A', 'path': 'a.txt'},
    {'title': 'Title B', 'path': 'b.txt'},
    {'title': 'Title C', 'path': 'c.txt'},
]

ix = index.open_dir("index")
writer = ix.writer()


for file_to_index in files_to_index:

    with open(file_to_index['path']) as f:
        for line_number, line in enumerate(f):
            writer.add_document(
                title=file_to_index['title'],
                path=file_to_index['path'],
                content=line,
                line_number=line_number,
                line_text=line,
            )
```

Comment: I see so there is no way for us to fit in the whole data within one `writer.add_document`?

Comment: @VictorVic - what's the reason for you wanting to map one text file to one document?

Comment: just thinking of a faster solution on the condition when I have multiple folders and files to be added to the writer and I only want to search for a particular keyword from a particular file directly haha.

Comment: @VictorVic - you can specify the path as part of the search query. See [Filter Results](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/searching.html#filtering-results) in the docs.